# How discard local project from repository?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

How discard local project from repository in IntelliJ IDEA 9? (like eclipse), help me :)

Answer (score 2):

File > Settings

In Version Control section, you will see Directory `<Project Root>` and VSC Subversion then click remove.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to delete the whole project from repository ? In this case you can use

svn del

or if you are using toroiseSVN you can just right click on the project folder and then select delete option.

Both ways will also delete your local copy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know that discard svn in IntelliJ IDEA 9.

Comment: If you select to delete a folder [pressing the DEL key] that is contained in the project in IntelliJ, it prompts if you want to delete also it from the repository. The project in svn is just a folder so deleting the folder is deleting the prj.